# Transparent background for Vbox

Tags: javafx

I am creating a GUI of chat bot. I have made entire pane into BorderPane and allocated Vbox to Center pame to have chats. Now i want to have background wallpaper to chat, which means a background image to Vbox. But the problem with this is, i could only get background image to onle the extent where chat is present(i mean stack is present). Can someone suggest me what to do in order to have the picture in the background for the whole?
For example: right now, if i have only one message in the chat then the background image is occupying only the space till that chat and i am getting white screen in the below

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wanted to I would set an ImageView behind the vbox or something like that.

So with that you can make the background transparent(VBox extends Node):

```
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
```

Then make it colorful with nearly the same command:

```
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff"); //white for example
```

OR:

```
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"); //a bit white
```